# Generate dynamic random variable in combination of alphabets and numbers for POST

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I want to generate a dynamic random variable like ASDF123 during Post request and it should range from 7 digit to 10 digit and it should be unique everytime(if in case 500 threads). This field is required to generate order numbers. I'm new to Jmeter so not much idea.

My Scenarios is like this: .> I have to generate a variable in combination of alphabets and letters(like this ->ASDF12345) for post then need to provide same variable to get to retrieve the same order for each thread. It is working fine if I generate random variable ie. minimum 1000 to max:9999 and passing same to post and get. But the req is that the order no. can be alphabets & numeric/numeric/alphabet. Please suggest how to proceed for the same. And yes everytime it should be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not generating anything, getting error that it cannot exceed 15. My Scenarios is like this: .> I have to generate a variable in  combination of alphabets and letters(like this ->ASDF12345) for post then need to provide same variable to get to retrieve the same order for each thread. It is working fine if I generate random variable ie. minimum 1000 to max:9999 and passing same to post and get. But the req is that the order no. can be alphabets & numeric/numeric/alphabet. Please suggest how to proceed for the same. And yes everytime it should be unique.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Functions as:

1. [RandomString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - First parameter how many characters (10 in your case) and second parameter choose your combination of alphabets and numbers:

   `${__RandomString(10,abcdefg1234567890)}`
2. Use [Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) if alphabets can be constant, and then add a number with 7-10 digits:

   `ASF${__Random(1000000,1000000000)}`

Or use [JSR223 element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to use Random in your programming language as Java/Groovy.

Comment: I tried using RandomString, but it is working for only one thread, for next thread it displays same value..please suggest how to run for all threads because I couldn't find option:(

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
${__javaScript(Math.random().toString(36).toUpperCase().substring(16))}
```

In jmeter it must looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not generating anything, getting error that it cannot exceed 15.